# Python array from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have two python variables.

```
Location = "myhome"
Iprange = ["10.0.0.3","10.0.0.9","10.0.0.234"]
```

I would like to pull those values from an external csv file called `details.csv` that looks like:

```
Myhome
10.0.0.3,10.0.0,9,10.0.0.234
```

I know this is probably simple but I am a very amateur programmer.

Comment: So which part of the process are you stuck on? Opening the file? Parsing its contents? Assigning to your variables? [Reading the tutorial?](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: I would like to replace the line iprange = ["10.0.0.3","10.0.0.9","10.0.0.234"] with a line from a csv file.

Comment: And what exactly about that are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Consider using other format, e.g. YAML

### `data.yaml`

```
MyHome:
- "10.0.0.3"
- "10.0.0.9"
- "10.0.0.234"
```

Which can be read as follows:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> fname = "data.yaml"
>>> with open(fname) as f:
...     cfg = yaml.load(f)
...
>>> cfg
{'MyHome': ['10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.9', '10.0.0.234']}
```

Before you run it, you have to install PyYaml

```
$ pip install pyyaml
```

## Other formats

Very similar approach works for JSON.

A bit more work but rather simple is using INI file format (see `ConfigParser`)

With CSV you can read the data, but CSV fits well for tabular structures and you seem to have rather tree like data.

Comment: I will give it a bash.  Why would you not use csv.

Comment: @HenryLevine With CSV have to care about data conversion and have more difficulties, if data are not tabular.

Comment: @HenryLevine CSV comes handy in the moment, there are many rows and when other people provide it to you (using Excel...)

Comment: I am going to YAML for now.  I still have a romantic relationship with csv.